# How stop gulp after doing the task?

Tags: sass, gulp, browser-sync, postcss, gulp-4

I need help, I use gulp4 and have a task build scss:

```
export const Style = () => src(path.style.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss([
        require('postcss-nested'),
        require('autoprefixer')
     ], {syntax: require('postcss-scss')}))
     .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
     .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
     .pipe(dest(path.style.dist))
     .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
```

and watching files this task:

```
export const WatchFiles = () =>
    watch(path.style.watch, Style);
```

This works wonderfully when I execute a default task, which is a task for development.

```
let RunServer = parallel(
    WatchFiles,
    Serve
);

let Build = series(
    Style,
    RunServer
);
```

Also, just in case, I will add a server task, maybe it will help

```
export function Serve(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: path.build,
            index: 'index.html'
        },
        ghostMode: true,
        notify: false,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 9000
    });

    done();
};
```

But if I just perform the "Style" task, it will not stop watching my files and will not complete the task. 
How to make so that when performing task, without task "WatchFiles", to stop builder?

[terminal](http://prntscr.com/n3dr86)

[link gitlab project](https://gitlab.com/hi.im.max.g/sonod)

Comment: I solved the problem myself, I added a callback for the watch function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a callback (done) in your style-function would solve the stopping problem.

```js
export const Style = (done) => {
  src(path.style.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss([
      require('postcss-nested'),
      require('autoprefixer')
    ], { syntax: require('postcss-scss') }))
    .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(dest(path.style.dist))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));

    done();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help me.

Comment: You run `gulp Style` und the task starts and do not finish?

Comment: Yes, she just stays in the terminal, as if she continues to monitor her.

Comment: I solved the problem myself, I added a callback for the watch function. Thanks for the tip